# Как поместить в цикл код с применнием ООП

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt5, qtimer

Есть код который получает `html` код страницы сайта для дальнейшего парсинга этого кода.

Мне нужно получать код с этого сайта примерно каждые `15` секунд для того чтобы быстро узнать о появлении чего либо на сайте.

Мне его нужно поместить в цикл, то есть чтобы в цикле снова загружалась таже страница `load(Qurl(url))` и я получал ее `html` код

Код:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import sys

url = 'https://www.google.com'

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()
html = Page(url).html
```

Если сделать так:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import sys

url = 'https://www.google.com'

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()

while 1:
    html = Page(url).html
    print(html)
```

То тогда после первой итерации цикла while код завершит свое выполнение с вот таким сообщением:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Нет `selenium` мне не походит из за большого потребления ресурсов.

Я знаю о существовании `requests`, я его не использую из-за того что мне требуется чтобы на странице выполнялся `javascript`.

Сайт `google.com` взят как пример.

Код выше взят [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147601/pyqt4-to-pyqt5-mainframe-deprecated-need-fix-to-load-web-pages%27)

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать и о каком цикле вы говорите.

Comment: @S.Nick Предоставил минимальный воспроизводимый пример и лучше объяснил что мне нужно сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Нельзя использовать в основном потоке циклы`** - это блокирует интерфейс.

В данном случае думаю **`QTimer`** вам подойдет.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl


class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        
    def _on_load_started(self, url):
        #print(f'_on_load_started(self, url): {url}')    
        self.load(QUrl(url))

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        #print(f'_on_load_finished')
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.parent.textEdit.setText(self.html)
        #print(f'Callable(self, html_str):...')


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        url = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/'
        
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(url)
        
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox.setMinimum(15 * 1000)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(60 * 1000 * 5)
        self.spinBox.setSuffix("   -> msec  ")          
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.value_changed)
                
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.spinBox, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button, 1, 2)
        
        self.page = Page(self)
        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(self.spinBox.value())
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)

    def on_clicked(self):
        if self.button.text() == "Start":
            self.timer.start()
            self.button.setText("Stop")
        else:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.button.setText("Start")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def value_changed(self, new_value):  
        self.timer.setInterval(new_value)
        
    def showTime(self):
        self.page._on_load_started(self.lineEdit.text())
    
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(400, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Мне не требуется интерфейс Все что мне нужно это получать `html` код сайта каждые **`15`** секунд.

Почувствуйте разницу

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer


url = 'https://www.google.com'

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        
        self.url = url
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        
        self._load_url()                                             # +++
        self.app.exec_()
        
    def _load_url(self):                                             # +++       
        self.load(QUrl(self.url))
#        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        print(self.html)                                             # +++
        QTimer.singleShot(15 * 1000, self._load_url)                 # +++
        
#        self.app.quit()
        
#html = Page(url).html
html = Page(url)                                                     # +++
```

Comment: Мне не требуется интерфейс 
Все что мне нужно это получать  html код сайта каждые 15 секунд

Comment: @ПавелЛядов я вам показал как каждые 15 секунд получать то что вам надо. Нужен вам интерфейс или не нужен - это решать вам, но я бы хорошо подумал об этом.

Comment: @ПавелЛядов также обратите внимание, что я сделал для вас возможность остановки процесса, изменение интервала запроса, изменение урла и все это в режиме реального времени.

Comment: @ПавелЛядов я добавил обновление в свой ответ, для того, чтобы вы увидели разницу.

Comment: @ПавелЛядов что не так?